# Insert Into Table () Values(),() partial insert due to error

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to do a partial insert of a statement similar to

```
INSERT INTO Classes (ID, Name, Subject)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Math'),
(2, 'Chris', 'English')
(3, 'Chris', 'Mathematics')
```

Given the above statement, if Subject in Classes was a varchar(10), the entire statement would fail due to Mathematics having 11 characters. I would like the successful inserts to proceed and the failed ones to be ignored, or better yet to be recorded in a separate table.

Is there any way to do this? Currently the application is performing inserts one at a time, reading from a flat file. Sometimes these files have 100,000+ records. Ultimately I would like to do data validation within the application prior to inserting into the database, but that change won't be approved for awhile. In the mean time, I can try to do this in batches by concatenating the VALUES set, but if any one of them fail the entire statement fails.

Comment: The short answer is no. Insert statements are atomic operations meaning that all fields are valid for insert or the insert does not happen. If you used a loop you could check for error (@@ERROR) after each insert state and then perform a operation such as an insert on an error table.

Comment: Can you change that to BCP? you can give an error file to it where it writes to records it's unable to insert into the table.

Comment: You could write each one as an atomic insert.

Comment: If the only problem with data validity is length of `VARCHAR` fields, then you can first insert all records into a temp table with `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns, then insert them into `Classes` table after filtering out all records with excessive field lengths.

Comment: Cannot use BCP. It is currently doing each one as an atomic insert, but doing 100,000+ inserts one at a time is time consuming and I'm sure it's not pretty to the log db. Unfortunately, the only problem isn't length of VARCHAR, it can be any reason why a record will fail to insert. This function within the application is a generic function used to insert any flat file record into a specified table.

Comment: You could look into SSIS, which allows errors to be ignored and logged.

Answer (score 1):

Partialy insert is not possible in single insert command.

Partialy insert way is to write separate insert statements:

INSERT INTO Classes (ID, Name, Subject) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Math'); -- pass

INSERT INTO Classes (ID, Name, Subject) VALUES (2, 'Chris', 'English'); -- pass

INSERT INTO Classes (ID, Name, Subject) VALUES (3, 'Chris', 'Mathematics'); -- brake